kya mai mere ammi ke chote bahen ke ladki se shadi kr skta hu
Can I marry my mother's younger sister's daughter?
She loves me very much. Is it respected in Islam? What kind of biological changes will occur in the next generation ? Can there be any problem in the future if we have child?
I have researched too much but I did not get any proper answer.

Salam. Welcome to Islam SE. It's respected in Islam without a doubt to marry your first cousin. Medical issues are a completely separate, but real issue. Sadly, however, this site is not for medical questions. Please check the link attached by UmH and confirm if it answers your question or not, and also read https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask .
